# \moderncvicons{awesome} giving error!

Tags: errors, fontspec, moderncv, fontawesome

I'm getting an error when compiling a resume of moderncv, with pdflatex in Mageia 2 i586 and TEXlive 2011. Why?
First I added the command `\moderncvicons{awesome}`, then I added `\usepackage{fontawesome}` and  `\usepackage{fontspec}`. Still getting error mgs, I wrote a simple *.tex file and compiled it with XeLatex, just to try out `fontawesome`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\faLinkedinSign
\end{document}
```

Guess what? Yes, still getting errors!
Can you please help me understand what's the problem? I even tried looking for TeXlive 2013 for Mageia but it's not out yet.

Comment: One error is that you haven't specified a language for `babel`. Other than that I don't see any error in your code.

Comment: Could you edit in the text of the errors, and also the `*File list*` you get in the `.log` when using `\listfiles` in your input.

Comment: TeX Live 2011 is very outdated and it surely hasn't `fontawesome`.

Comment: Well, **egreg** what can I do to get it to work? I get error also in Win7, as soon as I add the `\moderncvicons{awesome}` to the `resume.tex` preamble.

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled TeXLive and Kile because I came to know that when TeXLIve 2013 will come out, it won't be compatible with Mageia 2. I'm thinking of switching to some other distro by the end of the year, maybe Debian (KDE).

In Win7 with MikTeX 2.9, I managed to solve the problem by compiling the `resume.tex` with xelatex, (MikTeX asked me to install some packages, which I consented to).